# Changed server, get a Server Error (500) because of CSRF

Tags: django, cookies

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert in requests.

I changed server of my Django project and I *believe* that because of the [CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) I get a Server Error (500):

[image: Server Error (500)]

This only happens if I have a cookie stored from the previous server. If I open an incognito tab or delete my cookies the problem gets solved.

However what if a server change is needed in a production site? It's not possible all the users delete their cookies.

Therefore if I understand correctly and it's indeed the CSRF, how can I reset the user cookie if the Django sends a 500 error so as the user gets redirected to the homepage instead of receiving the above error?

Is it a correct way of solving the problem?

Comment: I'm' afraid I can't answer your question but to make sure that it is CSRF perhaps you can disable it as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11374627/1068167

Comment: I would suggest temporarily enabling debugging (`DEBUG = True`) to get some more info about the 500. Then we'll have more clues.