# CSRF Exempt inside view?

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf

I want to call a csfr protected class view inside other view in django, but this is giving me a CSFR not set error.

I tried to disable it with the `csfr_exempt` function ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31136060/10659353)), but it did not work at all:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views as django_auth_views
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def my_view(request):
    response = csrf_exempt(
            django_auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view()
    )(request)
```

It keeps giving me the same error.

Is there anyway I can do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by adding the token manually:

```py
    csrf_token = get_csrf_token(request)

    request.POST._mutable = True
    request.POST['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = csrf_token
    request.COOKIES[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME] = csrf_token
    request.POST._mutable = False

    response_from_password_reset_post = django_auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view()(request)
```